# How to break a span out of an iFrame

Tags: iframe, html

I modified a code I found online for spoilers to:

```
<a id="show_id" onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display=''; document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='none';" class="link">
  <img src="{link1}" alt="Stats">
</a>

<span id="spoiler_id" style="display: none;position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;">
  <a onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler_id').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('show_id').style.display='';" class="link">
    Hide
  </a>
  <br />
  <iframe src="{link2}" width="600" height="175" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</span>
```

What this should do: Display a picture with alt code "Stats" on page load. When the picture is clicked, the picture will disappear and a span with Hide {iFrame} should appear hovering 5 pixels from the left and 5 pixels from the top.

This works correctly when left by itself. However, I want to put it online through a source that breaks this code (the picture will show up, but it will not change when clicked.) If I iFrame the element, then it works, except the span stays inside the iFrame. What I want to know is if there is a way to break the span out of the iFrame. The other option would be to break the iframe in that code out of the iframe it is in.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Note: I do realize that there is an incredibly high chance this is impossible. If so, a confirmation of that is much appreciated.

Edit: Turns out the place I want to put it on does not support Javascript.

Comment: you try   top : -5px;  left -5px;    ?

Comment: Sadly, that keeps the element within the iFrame. Now some of it is impossible to see.

Comment: you could try top: -5px; left: -5px;  then change the z-index a lot higher ?   I'm pretty sure you are not allowed out of the iFrame though - it was just a thought , you could put a margin around the iFrame though and work out the positioning to make it appear that it is out

Comment: Thanks anyways :/ I will leave it up hoping someone has some magical answer, but I won't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe acts as a nested browser window. You aren't able to position elements outside an iframe just like you aren't able to position them outside your browser.

You could try to hide the span inside the iframe and build a new span in the parent window with the same contents.